# Changing position of anchor <a> in css not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, genesis

On my Worpdress website I have an anchor point on of my pages and I link to it from an external page. The problem is when I link to that page the top of the content is hidden by my fixed header. To try to fix this I added this in CSS:

```
.anchor{
position:relative;
top: -50px;
}
```

I know the position of the anchor has changed because I can see so using inspect element, but the link still takes me to the exact same place(covering the header)! I'm using the the genesis framework and my own custom child theme based on the genesis sample theme if that makes any difference. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure, you did refresh your browser page(s) several time to clear the browser cache?

Comment: Do padding/margin work instead of positioning?

Comment: Hi Yes I did clear the cache. And no padding/margin don't work but weirdly position:absolute; top: 0; (and all other absolute values) does make the link take me to the top of the page, but all relative values take me back to the original position.

Comment: Would you mind giving us a link to the page so we can have a look?

Comment: post a sample code in a fiddle.

Comment: I'm creating my site offline at the moment with WAMP so can't link to the site, but here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b3c5grny/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on one of my [Online Training](https://syzygal.com/product/cobit-foundation/) websites. It had a fixed header which always overlapped the content that i was linking to. The solution to this problem was to use a few lines of custom smooth scrolling script. You can find the implementation here.

```js
 $(".scroll").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         //calculate destination place
         var dest=0;
         if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
              dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
         }else{
              dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
         }
         //go to destination
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination1">Destination 1</a>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination2">Destination 2</a>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination3">Destination 3</a>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination4">Destination 4</a>
</nav>


<section id="destination1">
    <h1>Block 1</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <p>
        Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </p>
</section>

<section id="destination2">
    <h1>Block 2</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <p>
        Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </p>
</section>

<section id="destination3">
    <h1>Block 3</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <p>
        Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </p>
</section>

<section id="destination4">
    <h1>Block 4</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <p>
        Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </p>
</section>
```

Comment: The issue I am having is when clicking on a link from one page, which then takes me to an anchor on another page, rather than with link within the same page (ie <a href="http://exampl-website.com/page/#destination">)